# How to clear serial port rx buffer in Perl module

Tags: perl, serial-port

I am using `Device::SerialPort` Perlmodule. I would like to know if there is a facility to

- a) Clear the rx buffers of the serial port device [I would like to know the function for this]
- b) Figure out if there is data in the rx buffer by doing some read on some

subroutine/function exported by the Perlmodule. I am facing sync-up issues with my device. I go and write data while `rx` data is pending and so it is causing me problems. I would first like to read all of the `rx` data and then go and write my data.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: for a) there if a method `$PortObj->purge_rx;`.